# Excel VBA - Calculate column width in inches

Tags: excel, vba, column-width

I am trying to determine the width of a column in inches.
This formula sets the width to 5 inches but I cannot see how wide in inches column C is...

```
Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = Application.InchesToPoints(5) * (Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth / Columns("D:D").Width)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the column width by Application.InchesToPoints(1) (which is basically 72).

```
MsgBox Columns("C").Width / Application.InchesToPoints(1)
```

"Columnwidth" isn't in point, "Width" is in points.

Comment: If I use this to calculate the width of column D after setting it to 5 inches, it returns the value 4.854... Any ideas why?

Comment: Rather than hard-coding the `72`, it might be better to use `Application.InchesToPoints(1)`.

Comment: @Mush I've been playing for the last few minutes.  It seems to be successful if you execute your `Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = ...` statement **twice** (or more).  Not sure why.

Comment: That is weird... So I could include `Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = ...` twice for setting the width but `Columns("D:D").Width/Application.InchesToPoints(1)` once for reading the width.

Comment: @Mush Possibly, unless there is some case where it needs to be done **three** times :D  (That's the trouble with weird work-arounds - you never know whether they will work in all cases.)

Comment: @YowE3K That is brilliant... works perfectly! I would love to know why. If you come up with any other solution, do share it. Thanks!

Comment: @YowE3K, doesn't `.Width` and `.ColumnWidth` send a message to the event queue? I've a nagging feeling it does. Might be worth testing with a `DoEvents`?

Comment: @Ambie My earlier testing was done via the Immediate Window, so was equivalent to many `DoEvents` but, just to be sure, I tried the following `Columns("D").ColumnWidth = Application.InchesToPoints(5) * (Columns("D").ColumnWidth / Columns("D").Width)` `Debug.Print Columns("D").Width` `DoEvents` `Debug.Print Columns("D").Width` repeated three times.  The six results printed were `332.4` `332.4` `359.4` `359.4` `360` `360`.  So that test took 3 attempts before it was correct.  (I also tried putting `Stop` statements in the code, that didn't change anything.)

Comment: @YowE3K, doh, that was my last idea. I can't think why it would be doing that.